# Как сбросить псевдокласс `:invalid` для пустого инпута?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно чтобы пустой инпут не показывался как невалидный.
Попробовал [вот так](https://jsfiddle.net/alexey_m_ukolov/kkf1bs7e/) (и различные вариации на ту же тему) - не работает.
Поиск, разумеется, тоже не дал ответа.

```js
const $account = document.querySelector(`input[name=account]`);
const $form = $account.form;

$form.addEventListener(`submit`, (evt) => {
  console.log(3,
    $account.outerHTML,
    $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
    $account.getAttribute(`required`),
    $account.pattern,
    $account.required
  );
  $form.reportValidity();
  evt.preventDefault();
});

$account.addEventListener(`input`, () => {
  if (!$account.value) {
    $account.setCustomValidity(``);

    const pattern = $account.pattern;
    const isRequired = $account.required;

    console.log(1,
      $account.outerHTML,
      $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
      $account.getAttribute(`required`),
      $account.pattern,
      $account.required
    );

    $account.removeAttribute(`pattern`, ``);
    $account.removeAttribute(`required`);

    console.log(2,
      $account.outerHTML,
      $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
      $account.getAttribute(`required`),
      $account.pattern,
      $account.required
    );

    $form.dispatchEvent(new Event(`submit`));

    $account.setAttribute(`pattern`, pattern);

    if (isRequired) {
      $account.setAttribute(`required`, ``);
    }

    console.log(4,
      $account.outerHTML,
     $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
      $account.getAttribute(`required`),
      $account.pattern,
      $account.required
    );

    return;
  }

  if (!$account.checkValidity()) {
    $form.dispatchEvent(new Event(`submit`));

    return;
  }

  // ... остальной код ...
});
```

```css
input:invalid {
  background: hotpink;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="account" id="account" value="" pattern="^\s*\d{4,4}\s*$" required autofocus />
</form>
```

Comment: убери required, либо можно перебить стиль invalid, отдельным стилем для empty

Comment: @Grundy `input:empty` будет срабатывать всегда

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, когда пустой, хотя да, empty для инпута работает не так как я ожидал :)

Comment: У тебя ошибка в логике: если поле required - оно совершенно справедливо Invalid - если не заполнено.

Comment: @Grundy, я не хочу сделать пустое поле валидным, я хочу сбросить отображение валидации. Нормальная же ситуация: пользователь ввёл что-то невалидное, а потом удалил содержимое - нужно скинуть "невалидные" стили.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

1. Прописываем стили для невалидного для инпута с классом `hasval`.
2. Добавляем класс по первому вводу символа.

```js
const $account = document.querySelector(`input[name=account]`);
const $form = $account.form;

$form.addEventListener(`submit`, (evt) => {
  /*console.log(3,
    $account.outerHTML,
    $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
    $account.getAttribute(`required`),
    $account.pattern,
    $account.required
  );*/
  $form.reportValidity();
  evt.preventDefault();
});

$account.addEventListener(`input`, () => {
  $account.classList.add('hasval');
  if (!$account.value) {
    $account.setCustomValidity(``);

    const pattern = $account.pattern;
    const isRequired = $account.required;

    /*console.log(1,
      $account.outerHTML,
      $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
      $account.getAttribute(`required`),
      $account.pattern,
      $account.required
    );*/

    $account.removeAttribute(`pattern`, ``);
    $account.removeAttribute(`required`);

    /*console.log(2,
      $account.outerHTML,
      $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
      $account.getAttribute(`required`),
      $account.pattern,
      $account.required
    );*/

    $form.dispatchEvent(new Event(`submit`));

    $account.setAttribute(`pattern`, pattern);

    if (isRequired) {
      $account.setAttribute(`required`, ``);
    }

    /*console.log(4,
      $account.outerHTML,
     $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
      $account.getAttribute(`required`),
      $account.pattern,
      $account.required
    );*/

    return;
  }

  if (!$account.checkValidity()) {
    $form.dispatchEvent(new Event(`submit`));

    return;
  }

  // ... остальной код ...
});
```

```css
input.hasval:invalid {
  background: hotpink;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="account" id="account" value="" pattern="^\s*\d{4,4}\s*$" required autofocus />
</form>
```

Comment: на самом деле у автора ошибка в логике: если поле required - оно совершенно справедливо Invalid - если не заполнено

Comment: Да, имеет право на жизнь, но хотелось бы без лишних классов обойтись.

Comment: @Grundy формально да, а с точки зрения UX это не совсем ок. так поля с `required` не будут иметь обычного стиля и пользователь сразу будет видеть *неправильно* заполненные поля, хотя он еще ничего не заполнял :-)

Answer (score 1):

Предложили вот такой вариант (интересное решение, но [поддержка браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown) не идеальная):

```js
const $account = document.querySelector(`input[name=account]`);
const $form = $account.form;

$form.addEventListener(`submit`, (evt) => {
  $form.reportValidity();
  evt.preventDefault();
});

$account.addEventListener(`input`, () => {
  if (!$account.value) {
    $account.setCustomValidity(``);

    const pattern = $account.pattern;
    const isRequired = $account.required;

    $account.setAttribute(`pattern`, ``);
    $account.removeAttribute(`required`);

    $form.dispatchEvent(new Event(`submit`));

    $account.setAttribute(`pattern`, pattern);

    if (isRequired) {
      $account.setAttribute(`required`, ``);
    }

    return;
  }

  if (!$account.checkValidity()) {
    $form.dispatchEvent(new Event(`submit`));

    return;
  }

  // ... остальной код ...
});
```

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid {
  background: hotpink;
  color: #fff;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="account" id="account" value="" pattern="^\s*\d{4,4}\s*$" placeholder=" " required autofocus />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще один вариант:

1. Запишем стили для валидации в тег `style`, поместим в самое начало символы открывающего многострочного комментария.
2. Для условия `if (!$account.value)` добавим `else`, куда поместим операцию удаления символов комментария

   2.1. При необходимости можно добавить вставку символов комментария обратно, для этого достаточно в `if (!$account.value)` добавить `$invalid.innerHTML = '/*' + $invalid.innerHTML` — так всегда при незаполненном поле будут отображаться стандартные стили, хотя, по-моему, это не совсем правильно.

```js
const $account = document.querySelector(`input[name=account]`);
const $invalid = document.getElementById('invalid');
const $form = $account.form;

$form.addEventListener(`submit`, (evt) => {
  /*console.log(3,
    $account.outerHTML,
    $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
    $account.getAttribute(`required`),
    $account.pattern,
    $account.required
  );*/
  $form.reportValidity();
  evt.preventDefault();
});

$account.addEventListener(`input`, () => {
  if (!$account.value) {    
    $account.setCustomValidity(``);

    const pattern = $account.pattern;
    const isRequired = $account.required;

    /*console.log(1,
      $account.outerHTML,
      $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
      $account.getAttribute(`required`),
      $account.pattern,
      $account.required
    );*/

    $account.removeAttribute(`pattern`, ``);
    $account.removeAttribute(`required`);

    /*console.log(2,
      $account.outerHTML,
      $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
      $account.getAttribute(`required`),
      $account.pattern,
      $account.required
    );*/

    $form.dispatchEvent(new Event(`submit`));

    $account.setAttribute(`pattern`, pattern);

    if (isRequired) {
      $account.setAttribute(`required`, ``);
    }

    /*console.log(4,
      $account.outerHTML,
     $account.getAttribute(`pattern`),
      $account.getAttribute(`required`),
      $account.pattern,
      $account.required
    );*/

    return;
  } else {
    if( $invalid.innerHTML.charAt(0) === '/' ) $invalid.innerHTML = $invalid.innerHTML.substr(2);
  }

  if (!$account.checkValidity()) {
    $form.dispatchEvent(new Event(`submit`));

    return;
  }

  // ... остальной код ...
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="account" id="account" value="" pattern="^\s*\d{4,4}\s*$" required autofocus />
</form>

<style id="invalid">/*
  input:invalid {
    background: hotpink;
    color: #fff;
    font-style: italic;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Ну, это уж совсем костыльный костыль :) Да и если инпутов на странице с различным состоянием будет несколько, то всё поломается. Похоже, что решение с классом самое подходящее.

Comment: Ну это да, вариант исключительно теоретический )

Answer (score 0):

Все просто, пишем в `CSS`:

```css
input:invalid:not(input:empty), 
input.invalid:not(input:empty)
```